# history.pushState() $_GET parameters not being set in chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, html5-history

It seems that $_GET parameters aren't passed properly when using chrome, however it does work using FF. If a link has trailing arguments like `page.php?id=10&something=else`, the URI changes to just `page.php`.

Is there a way to keep those $_GET parameters in the URI?

Comment: Got the same issue, did you find a solution ? (he doesn't like the & )

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=365618